# When to use which ability estimates method?

Tags: item-response-theory

There are several methods in IRT ability estimation,such as :

- expected a-posteriori ("EAP"),
- Bayes modal ("MAP"),    weighted
- likelihood estimation ("WLE"),
- maximum likelihood ("ML"),
- expected a-posteriori for sum scores ("EAPsum")

Are there any guidelines as to when each is appropriate?